# Взаимное блокирование потоков

Tags: потоки-данных, java, многопоточность

```
public class One extends Thread{
  public void run(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Two());
    t.start();   //запускается поток в объекте класса Two
    t.join();    //данный поток ждет окончания выполнения потока в объекте класса Two
  }
}

class Two extends Thread{
  One one;
  public void run(){
    //здесь нужно запустить метод join на объекте класса One <cсылка на One>.join() 
    // для блокировки выполнения потока в объекте класса Two пока не завершится 
    // выполнения потока объекта класса One, где взять эту ссылку?
    one.join();
  }
}

class Go {
  public static void main(String[] agrv){    
    new Thread (new One()).start();
  }
}
```

Результатом должна быть взаимная блокировка потоков. Но выбрасывается NullPointerExcepton/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class One extends Thread{

public void run(){

Thread t = new Thread(new Two(this));

t.start();   //запускается поток в объекте класса Two
t.join();    //данный поток ждет окончания выполнения потока в объекте класса Two

}

}

class Two extends Thread{

One one;

public Two (One o) {
 one = o;
}
 public void run(){

    //здесь нужно запустить метод join на объекте класса One <cсылка на One>.join() 
           // для блокировки выполнения потока в объекте класса Two пока не завершится 
           // выполнения потока объекта класса One, где взять эту ссылку?
 one.join();

}

}

class Go {

public static voi main(String[] agrv){

 new Thread (new One()).start();

} }
```